# Unexpectedly label and tableview found nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I am loading a `nib` for `leftSlideMenu` menu is added successfully but when I am setting `lbltext` or reloading table view getting error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an option value. below is my code.

these are outlets which are connected

```
@IBOutlet weak var lblUserName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblUserEmployee: UILabel!
```

This method is in my UIView class

```
func prepareScreenWithView(navigationController: UINavigationController, viewSize: UIView) {

    nibView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("LeftSlideMenu", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! UIView
    navController = navigationController
    nibView.tag = 100
    var tempRect = nibView.frame
    print(tempRect)

    lblUserEmployee.text = "Employee Name" // here i am getting the error.


    tempRect =  CGRect(x: -200, y: 0, width: tempRect.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    viewSize.addSubview(self.nibView)
    lblUserEmployee.text = " "
    UIView.transition(with: self.nibView, duration: 2, options: [.beginFromCurrentState], animations: {
        tempRect.origin.x +=  200
        self.nibView.frame = tempRect

    }) { (success) in

    }
}
```

This is the @IBAction which of UIViewController class

```
@IBAction func onClick_Hamberger(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if !isShowingMenu {

        instanceOfLeftSlideMenu.prepareScreenWithView(navigationController: self.navigationController!, viewSize: self.view)
        btnHamburgerMenu.frame.origin.x += 200
        isShowingMenu = true
    } else {

        instanceOfLeftSlideMenu.hideSlideMenu(navigationController: self.navigationController!, viewSize: self.view)
        btnHamburgerMenu.frame.origin.x -= 200
        isShowingMenu = false
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: have you rechecked if the outlets are connected properly?

Comment: yes outlets are connected properly. There is also a table view same error while reloading table.

Comment: check like this:   if let label = lblUserEmployee { label.text = "Employee Name" }

Comment: i am getting nil so how to set label text??

Comment: @S.Bharti can you share demo project?

Comment: can you send me your email id?? i will send you

Comment: Where is your app crashing?

Comment: Where is you app crashing .. at least point out the variable or the outlet ..

Comment: outlet lblUserName.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass "**nil**" for parameter ***owner*** of Bundle.main.loadNibNamed.

```
nibView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("LeftSlideMenu", owner: nil, options: nil)
```